# Can't import context before initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to import my created context from my App.js, in a child component.

App.js

```
export const FilterContext = React.createContext("test");

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Navigation />
                <Hero />

                <FilterContext.Provider value="hello">
                    <OfferSorting />

                    <div className="wrapper">
                        <div className="container">
                            <Offer />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <NewOfferButton />
                </FilterContext.Provider>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Then I want to access my context in `<OfferSorting />`

OfferSorting.js

```
import { FilterContext } from "../../../App";

export default class OfferSorting extends React.Component {
    static contextType = FilterContext;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.context)
    }
}
```

But in `OfferSorting.js` it will throw the error `Cannot access 'FilterContext' before initialization`. How can I access my context, and not use props?

Comment: Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12397)